# How to insert multiple row or records or items from listview to ms access using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, ms-access-2007

I am working on a program which saves multiple rows to MS access 2007. My problem is, it only saves the first row when the listview has 2 or more rows/items then an error will pop up but if the listview has one item only it saves smoothly without any error, i want to save all the rows or items in the listview in just one click.

here is the code of the button:

```
Dim connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Soumen_DB.mdb;"
 Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(connection)
  myconnection.Open()

For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
 Dim sqlq2 As String = "INSERT INTO [ProductSold] ([ReceiptNo], [VATNo], [ProductID], [ProductName], [Price], [Quantity], [Amount], [DiscountPer], [DiscountAmount], [GSTPer], [GSTAmount], [TotalAmount]) 
        VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12)"

 Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(sqlq2, myconnection)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", receiptNo)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", "123456")
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", "123456")
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d6", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d7", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d8", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(5).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d9", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(6).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d10", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d11", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(8).Text)
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("d12", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(9).Text)
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
   Next
   MsgBox("Data Saved...")
```

Comment: ...and exactly what error *pops up*?  That is a rather crucial piece of information.  Also note that the ListView is not a grid and quite suboptimal for dbOps.  Price, Quantity and Amount are likely numeric columns, but you are treating them as strings.  Also, only the first column can be edited.

Comment: I solved it.....